# Equalize the three numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

You have three numbers, $x, y, z$. You are allowed the following two operations on these numbers.

- Choose any two numbers and increase them by $1$.
- Else choose any number and increase them by $2$.

Find the minimum number of operations to make the three numbers equal.

Eg. $x = 2, y = 5, z = 4$. Minimum operations is $2$.

I cannot seem to come up with the solution. Please help.

Comment: What is your question? Make it clear

Comment: I have clearly mentioned it in the question.

Find the minimum number of operations to make the three numbers equal.
Were you the downvote?

Comment: I cannot seem to come up with the solution-Solution for what??

Comment: Just hint: first, note that each step increases the sum ($a+b+c$) by $2$; so after $2$ steps the sum $a''+b''+c''$ is...; so you can deduce the target value.

Comment: Increase x and z by 1 and then increase x by 2

Comment: @Love Invariants: q.e.d.

Comment: @LoveInvariants *facepalm* I am not asking the solution to the example. Rather for a generic $x, y, z$

Comment: @Oleg567, divisible by two?

Comment: @Raghav: I mean: if $x+y+z=2+5+4=11$, then after $2$ steps we'll have $x''+y''+z''=11+2\times 2 = 15$, so $x''=y''=z''=\ldots$, so you'll see how to correct each of the numbers $x,y,z$. (for example, $y$ needs no correction).

Comment: @Raghav sum up the numbers. Let it be s. Now your sum should be either equal to 3n or 3(n+1) where n is highest value amongst x,y,z. Whichever is of same parity as s will be the ultimate sum.

Comment: For example, 3n=15, 3(n+1)=18. Since 15 is of the same parity as 11. So you ultimate sum will be 15. Now 15-11=4=2.2 So 2 will be the answer.

Comment: Cool insight. Can you tell me how did you come up with this?

Comment: Just writing the answer.

Comment: I think it's sufficient to look at the values in mod 2.

Comment: @MattiP., can you please explain?

Comment: I just figured that in mod 2, it's possible to make three times the first one operation to increase all of the variables by 2 (choose xz, xy and finally yz); and the second operation doesn't change the mod 2 value of the chosen variable. ... Just my train of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x+y+z=s$
where $x>y\ge z$ or $x\ge y>z$
Now the ultimate sum should be either $3x$ or $3(x+1)$ as all the numbers will be equal and the sum will have the same parity as the initial(it increase by 2)
Now since highest value i.e $x=5$
So $3x=15$ and $3(x+1)=18$
Parity of $x+y+z=11 $ is odd as $15$. So $15$ will be the ultimate sum.
Now, $15-11=4$ which is increase in $s$.
At each step it increases by $2$ so minimum steps=${4\over 2} =2$

PS: Variables are different than the ones in the question.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. I just don't understand how you came up with the $3x$ or $3(x+1)$ part. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Raghav- We know that either the sum of all the numbers will be odd or even and will be divisible by $3$. Also one of $3x$ and $3(x+1)$ will be even and odd each. And $3x , 3(x+1)$ is the smallest sum possible for $x,y,z$ which means it will be obtained in smallest number steps.